# Extract version from XML with Windows Batch

Tags: windows, cmd, xml-parsing

I have a XML file generated by Visual Studio that contains the version of the product, hence the tag will always be there just the value changes. 
I need to extract the version with windows command line somehow. This is the tag in the file and I need only the version number "1.0.0.0":

```
 <?define BuildVersion = 1.0.0.0 ?>
```

Is there a built in tool (maybe with `findstr`) that can accomplish this?

Comment: Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40784439/276311) I came up with this: `for /F "tokens=4 delims= " %%E in ('
    findstr "BuildVersion" "file.xml"
') do @echo %%E`

Comment: Results in `%%E was unexpected at this time`

Comment: Use a single % instead of two when running from the command line.

Comment: Awesome it works! Can you put it as an answer please

Comment: @AdrianoP, the spaces around `=` are optional, so I would include that character to the delimiters like `delims== ` and use `tokens=3` instead...

Comment: In general it is a better idea to use a language that is capable of handling XML data natively rather than treating them like normal text...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use for /F loop to parse the output of findstr and extract the text you need (using space as delimiter, get the 4th token):

```
for /F "tokens=4 delims= " %%E in ('
    findstr "BuildVersion" "file.xml" 
') do @echo %%E
```

*Use a single % instead of two when running from the command line though.*

For a more comprehensive information please check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40784439/276311).