# Using FINDSTR command range

Tags: batch-file

Assuming that i've the following txt.file:

```
Jenkins Build Received: Request type: ScanRequestRequest ID: 2Assessee name: Jenkins.ZIP" jenkins_logs.txt
```

This build happens every weekend and the **ScanRequestRequest ID number** (in this case is number two) **is always different**.

What is the best approach to use the findstr command where? I've tried some examples but without any success:

```
findstr /C:"Jenkins Build Received: Request type: ScanRequestRequest ID: *Assessee name: Jenkins.ZIP" jenkins_logs.txt
```

And:

```
findstr /C:"Jenkins Build Received: Request type: ScanRequestRequest ID: [0-9]Assessee name: Jenkins.ZIP" jenkins_logs.txt
```

I saw too the findstr r/ option but i need the program catch this string literally (the jenkins_log is a file with too many lines (over 10000).

I'm new with this thing of batch. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what do you want to do? You explain, but do not show what you want to achieve

Comment: you need a regex to search for this, which you must call with `findstr /r`. But what do you mean by "literally"? Obviously if the string is match, the whole literal line must be printed

Comment: @GerhardBarnard i need to use this string in a if condition that i have (if the string exist, starts another batch), if not (close the program). The if condition is always returning false because the ID number is always different.

Comment: @phuclv I've tried findstr /r but never result because he shows everything. And example: 03/14/19 21:17:57Jenkins Build Received: Request type: ScanRequestRequest ID: 2Assessee name: Jenkins.ZIP03/14/19 23:17:57Jenkins Build Finished: Request type: ScanRequestRequest ID: 2Assessee name: Jenkins.ZIP03/14/19 23:18:10Jenkins Build Received: Request type: ScanRequestRequest ID: 3Assessee name: Jenkins_2.ZIP03/15/19 03:11:32Jenkins Build Finished: Request type: ScanRequestRequest ID: 3Assessee name: Jenkins.ZIP_2

I don't want this.

Comment: then it's a duplicate of [Findstr - Return only a regex match](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40780784/995714)

Comment: `/R` and `/C` can be used together, which is what you need here; the best way to match a single decimal digit is `[0123456789]` (since `[0-9]` might also match characters `²` and `³`); to match one or more digits, use `[0123456789][0123456789]*`...

Comment: @aschipfl A huge thanks for you my friend! It's working! :D